# android unable to click button after return

Tags: android, return, onclicklistener

I have a view to create an account. If the save button is clicked and any of the fields are left open, it displays a toast. If all fields are filled in, the account is saved. I tried to accomplish this with an onClickListener that has an iteration through all the fields. It works perfectly if a field is not filled in and it works perfectly if alle fields are filled, but when a field isn't filled, I type something in there, try to save again and the button doesn't do anything.

I think it has something to do with the return, but I don't know what to do else. If the return wouldn't be there, I would get a toast for each field that isn't filled in.

Here's the relevant code:

```
private void registerButtonListeners() {
    mCRUDAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mEditTexts.length; i++) {       
                if(mEditTexts[i].getText().length() == 0){
                    CommonCode.showToast(mNoTextTitles[i], mContext, mViewGroup);
                    mEmptyField = 1;
                    return;
                }
            };
            if (mEmptyField == 0){
                saveState();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never resetting your flag back to 0!

so...

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mEmptyField = 0;//RIGHT HERE (give them the benefit of the doubt)
            for (int i = 0; i < mEditTexts.length; i++) {       
                if(mEditTexts[i].getText().length() == 0){
                    CommonCode.showToast(mNoTextTitles[i], mContext, mViewGroup);
                    mEmptyField = 1; //You were too optimistic, they failed.
                    return;
                }
            };
            if (mEmptyField == 0){
                saveState();
            }
        }
    });
```

Now, you're doing this test for the first time, every time. Otherwise, you go through and set that flag to 1, and next time, even though your loop never finds a match, when you get to the if mPentyField == 0 test, it fails cause you set that to 1 in the previous go around.

Comment: No need to feel dumb... if I had a nickel for every time I missed something obvious... :)